# Disputed Close Vote Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I came across (and failed) this as a Close Vote review audit today:

*[ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems)*

It looked very off-topic for *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"* reasons to me.

Has a quick Google, and apparently posting here specifying the dubious audit is useful.

Let me know if this helps, or if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that ADB is a tool for Android developers, why would you consider this to be off-topic?  No code is necessary to replicate the issue that they're observing; if nothing else, installing ADB locally and executing it *might* be enough to replicate the issue.

When it comes to questions seeking debugging help, you have to be certain that code is involved at some point.  ADB is a tool which interacts with Android applications at a specific level, but it itself doesn't really touch *code*.

Since I'm not 100% sure if you knew this or not, it would've been best to skip the review.  Only review questions you're certain on.  Skip the ones that you have any doubts on.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - will skip more often now. I've seen numerous questions closed for dropping in an error message and little else, so thought it might be worth putting here in case there was a quirk in picking out the review question. However, seems that's not the case, so appreciate the advice to use in future.

Answer (score 1):

The Close reason you cite, is meant for questions about debugging *specific* pieces of code. Without seeing that code, such questions are hard to answer.

This is a question about a tool often used by developers, which makes it on-topic.  It doesn't ask for help on a specific programming problem, but instead asks how to address a problem with a tool. A problem that the user has on *all* their code.

This makes the question on-topic and useful for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks - I'd have seen this question as unsuitable for a number of reasons, including "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking"; however, happy to cede to your experience here. Appreciate the prompt answer.

Comment: @SRack A good rule of thumb is to leave the unclear and too broad reasons alone if you're reviewing in a technology you're not familiar with. Of course you're going to have no idea what the person is asking for if you have no experience in the technology.